# TFS API: How to check if a user has administrator privileges on a Project Collection and Project?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I need to check if a user (who is connected to a Project Collection) is a member of the administrators group of the Project Collection or not. Also, I need to do the same for a Project.

I need the most correct way of doing so.

Currently I am using the following method, but I'm not sure if it is the perfect way.

```
//Get the IdentityManagementService from the Project Collection
IIdentityManagementService LIdentityService = (IIdentityManagementService)ProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IIdentityManagementService));    
//Search for user identity by user name
TeamFoundationIdentity LUserIdentity = LIdentityService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, {Username}, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
//Get Guid of the same Project Collection to use as scope
String Id = ProjectCollection.InstanceId.ToString();
//Get the Administrators group for Project Collection scope *
TeamFoundationIdentity LAdminIdentity = LIdentityService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AdministratorsGroup, Id, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

IsAdmin = false;
//Traverse through the groups of the user and check if administrators group is also one of them
foreach (IdentityDescriptor member in LUserIdentity.MemberOf)
{
    if (member.Identifier.Equals(LAdminIdentity.Descriptor.Identifier, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        IsAdmin = true;
}
```

This works fine on one setup but on another setup of Team Foundation Server it gives the following error while getting the administrators group.
"The Team Foundation Identity Scope {Guid of the project collection} does not exist."

Comment: Where/How do you define `ProjectCollection.InstanceId`? This differs between TeamProjectCollections and of course between TFS Server.  The error says you are using a non existing Guid, so I expect you use the Guid from one server on another one.

Comment: Yes instance id differs between project collections.
In the function I am searching for the Administrators Group Identifier at Project Collection Level, so I have to pass the Instance Id of the project collection.

I have taken care to use the project collection from the same server.

Comment: But it seems that you switch the TFS server instance somewhere, but not the ProjectCollection. Or what do you mean with "*This works fine on one setup but on another setup of Team Foundation Server it gives the following error" ?

Comment: Have you considered querying the groups by display name (i.e. `Project Collection Administrators`) rather than the Guid of the collection?

Comment: @MikeR - I don't switch the TFS instance anywhere. By "one setup" and "another setup" I meant that I have two installations of Team Foundation Server on two different machines with their clients on the same respeective machines. When I tested it on one it worked but it gave the above given error on the other machine.

Comment: @JamesTupper - Yes I tried using "Project Collection Administrators" and it worked. But I am not sure if the name "Project Collection Administrators" will be constant in case of other locales and languages or if the user is allowed to change it. Is there some way I could confirm that.

Comment: So you have 2 Application Tier server that uses the same database? Usually if you do something like load balancing, both servers should be identically, but it sounds that they don't support the Collections. If the 2 server have their own databases, than this can't work using specific ID.   Nevertheless, `Project Collection Administrators` and `Project Administrators` always exists as groups. PCA can't be modified, while PA can be changed/renamed.

Comment: OK so are you completely sure that PCA account name cannot be modified and stays the same?
Because my code will then be completely dependent on it.

Comment: Also, there are no linked servers or databases. I have two machines (for testing) running two different completely independent instances of Team Foundation Server with nothing related to each other. They are only for testing.
The problem was that my earlier code worked on one but not on the other. So I wasn't sure if my code was actually universal.
But if you can tell me for sure that "Project Collection Administrators" stays the same regardless of the language or locale or anything, then I can use the account name to search for the administrators group.

Thanks for the help by the way.